# What font is being used for the GUI in "The Waters of Mars"?

Tags: doctor-who

The UI design in Russel's era of Doctor Who always baffles me but at the same time I feel like it'd be pretty fun to try and replicate in a game or something. Does anyone know what font this is?

[image: waters of mars font example]

Comment: The Graphic Design stack has a font identification tag.They require trying a font checking service, like WhatTheFont.com before posting.

Comment: I just checked it on WhatTheFont.com - no match. The “W” is distinctive. If I could only remember how to migrate things to another stack, I’d be really helpful!

Comment: Temporal Shift Expanded has some similarities but is not an exact match. It seems like the same font has been used for all of the text on the edges of the screen. I can't make out any other words using that distinctive 'W' though, which does make me wonder if it was tweaked to make it more visually strking (and more alien) for the word 'WARNING'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the exact match - the font is called 'Colony Wars'.

Here's how I did it:
On the official Doctor Who website, there used to be a flash game called 'The Waters of Mars' where you had to move pipes to transport the deadly water away from Bowie Base One.

I downloaded the flash game (.swf) file for this game, and used a flash decompiler to look inside the file. It told me the name of this font.

Download it here: https://www.wfonts.com/font/colony-wars

I have also discovered the names for a whole lot of other Doctor Who fonts, so if you would like any other font names, don't hesitate to send me a message :)

Answer (score 12):

I think this font is pretty close! The W is slightly different, but most of the characters are very close. There are also some alternate characters that might be even closer.

[image: Xirod font]

Here's the link to the installable font:

[Xirod DaFont Link](https://www.dafont.com/xirod.font)

Comment: That is such a close match I'd stick my neck out and say that either the designers took that font and tweaked it ever so slightly, or someone created it based on the episode.